# How can i parse/get only the number inside the string/s?

Tags: c#, winforms

The variable PostedId contain for example 7 strings.
For example in index 0 i see: {"id":"1234567890"}
I want in the loop FOR
To parse/extract from the current index string only the number.
So in the line :

```
objFacebookClient.Delete(PostedId[i]).ToString();
```

Instead PostedId[i] will be {"id":"1234567890"} it should be only: 1234567890 only the number.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            var responsePost = "";
            try
            {
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(AccessPageToken);
                for (int i = 0; i < PostedId.Count; i++)
                {
                    objFacebookClient.Delete(PostedId[i]).ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get numbers in your `string` then parsing them to `int`.

If it is, you can use [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get numbers inside a string and use [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to parsing it.

For example;

```
string s = "{\"id\":\"1234567890\"}";
char[] array = s.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
string s1 = new string(array);
int i;
if (Int32.TryParse(s1, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out i))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Output will be;

```
1234567890
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/vQl55t)</kbd>.

Comment: Soner it is working but the result is not good. The number in the string for example is like this: 344087212396598_344788945659758 i need to keep the format of the number including the "_" in the middle. In your code the result is: 344087212396598344788945659758 but i need it to be : 344087212396598_344788945659758

Comment: why don't you check my answer by this method you can get output like "abc12345sg456789" Output : 12345 456789 numbers one by one

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment under [Soner Gönül`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21875420/336648), you probably want to do something like this.

This is a modification of that answer; just outputting the resulting string, without parsing it to an int, which obviously will not work when including "_".

Please make sure you include details like this in your original post in future questions.

```
string input = "{\"id\":\"12345_67890\"}";
char[] array = input.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '_').ToArray();

// Will contain: "12345_67890"
string result = new string(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy enough to do with a string.split or making use of a regex to extract the number part of the id.  I can give an example if needed

Answer (score 0):

The format you have here is looks like Json.

You can use
[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to parse your string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regx for this, 
5 is minimum digits you want, 
numberonly is output, strText is input text

```
Regex _Regex = new Regex("\\d{5,}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matchList = _Regex.Matches(strText);
string NumberOnly = string.Empty;
if (matchList.Count == 0)
    NumberOnly = matchList(0).ToString();

//if strText = "Test12345Test6789"
//Output will be
//matchList(0) = 12345
//matchList(1) = 6789
```

Answer (score 0):

Make class called for example 'FaceBookResponse':

```
public class FaceBookResponse{
  public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `JavaScriptSerializer` (Reference System.Web.Extensions):

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

In the for loop use this:

```
var obj = serializer.Deserialize<FaceBookResponse>();
objFacebookClient.Delete(obj.id).ToString();
```